# Day JS in Nuxt guessing timezone using tz.guess() not a function

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, dayjs

I'm using the `@nuxtjs/dayjs` module v1.4.1 in my Nuxt 2 project. I need to guess the user's timezone and set a datetime in their timezone. When I try to run my JS, I get an error telling me it's not a function, what am I missing?

```js
// Day JS config
dayjs: {
  locales: ['en'],
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  plugins: [
    'utc',
    'timezone',
    'relativeTime',
    'advancedFormat',
    'localizedFormat',
    'customParseFormat'
  ]
},
```

Called like in a function:

```js
this.$dayjs().tz.guess()
```

returns error:

> this.$dayjs(...).tz.guess is not a function

Comment: Could you debug and try to see what does `this.$dayjs().tz` contain? Is it filled? Is `guess` undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
this.$dayjs.tz.guess()
```

Refer https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/guessing-user-timezone